# I can't connect to database inside docker container using Laravel application

Tags: sql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to dockerize my Laravel application for a couple of days now. The main problem is that my database server (which is SQL database) seems to not work. I'm using docker desktop and when the Laravel part of my project works when I'm trying to use the logging feature I'm getting this error:

[image: error]

##### `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services: 
    main:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        command: 'php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0'
        volumes:
            - /test/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: employee_app
            MYSQL_ROOT: root
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "true"
        volumes:
            - /db_dumps/employee_app.sql:/docker-entrypointinitdb.d/employee_app.sql
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
```

##### `.env`

```bash
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=employee_app
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

##### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql sockets
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer​ | php -- \
     --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN composer install --ignore-platform-reqs
```

I have tried everything, like setting `DB_HOST` to `localhost` and the name of the container which holds the database. The other thing I've noticed is that the binding address is empty when I create a container regardless if I set ip or not.

[image: log]

Comment: you must use `DB_HOST=db`, it must be the container name so docker can resolve it, but will only work inside a container, if you try to run any command that involves the database, it will not work if you are running it outside a container. Try setting `DB_PORT=33060`, by default it is `3306` but if it is not working and you see the binding to `33060`, try it out. You can also use [`laravel/sail`](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sail)

Comment: The output pretty clearly says it's running on port 33060 so you must have mistyped something somewhere along the way.

Comment: If a previous-but-now-fixed typo (like `33060`) is still haunting you, maybe you're caching your config (don't cache config in local dev env).  Try clearing your cache.